# Django datetimefield invalid for certain locales

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

I don't have any date input formats defined, my form field is:

```
    expiry_date = forms.DateTimeField(widget=SelectDateWidget,
                                      required=False)
```

I'm using the locales `en` (English) and `zh-hans` (Simplified Chinese).

According to PyCharm debugger, the POST values are identical in either language:

```
self.request.POST['expiry_date_day'] = u'25'
self.request.POST['expiry_date_month'] = u'9'
self.request.POST['expiry_date_year'] = u'2015'
```

However I get the error only in `zh-hans`.

In the `form.clean()` method the `self.cleaned_data['expiry_date']` value is missing, so I'm guessing it's being stripped out due to failing a previous validation error.

**Fixed**:

I fixed this by adding the following to my settings:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%Y-%m-%d', '%Y/%m/%d')
```

And then apply this to the specific DateTimeField:

```
expiry_date = forms.DateTimeField(widget=SelectDateWidget,
                                  input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS,
                                  required=False)
```

Specifically `'%Y-%m-%d'` is needed to keep `en` happy, whilst `'%Y/%m/%d'` allows `zh-hans` and `zh-hant` to function correctly.

I found this by drilling down in the debugger and figuring out what value was passing though `DateTimeField.to_python()`.

I'll leave the question open though, as I'd still like to understand exact why they are formatted differently by locale, and if there's a more obvious way to figure out which formats to allow and when and I don't think the solution should be "step-through the debugger until you find the line of code!"